# getting Subset of 2 arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have `2` `NSArray`, lets call it as `CountriesArray` and `UNCountriesArray`. The `CountriesArray` contains all the countries in the world and the `UNCountriesArray` contains all the countries that belongs to the united nations.

I Want to get the `subset` of the 2 arrays. so finally i should get an array that has the countries that does not belong to the united nations. Can some one help me write the `objective-c` code that gets the subset of the 2 arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sets:

```
NSMutableSet *countriesSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:countriesArray];
NSSet *unSet = [NSSet setWithArray:unCountriesArray];
[countriesSet minusSet:unSet];
// countriesSet now contains only those countries who are not part of unSet
```

Keep in mind that the members of the set are unsorted. If you want to have a sorted array, you will have to re-sort the result.

Comment: How can i save the result to a `NSArray`? Is `[countriesSet minusSet:unSet];` returning a `NSArray`

Comment: `NSArray *resultArray = [countriesSet allObjects];` The documentation is your friend. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the removeObjectsInArray method of NSMutableArray to do this.  For example:

```
NSMutableArray *countriesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
NSArray *unCountriesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2", @"4", nil];
[countriesArray removeObjectsInArray:unCountriesArray];
NSLog(@"Countries array: %@", countriesArray);
```

Comment: Cant `countriesArray` also be a `NSArray` ? does it have to be a `NSMutableArray`?